# Migrating from Ext JS 2 to Ext JS 4

Tags: extjs

I am getting this error on page load itself.

> Error: [Ext.extend] Attempting to extend from a class which has not been loaded on the page.
>   javascript//ext-4.1.1a/ext-all-debug.js
>   Line 4391

I'm not able to render the page at all. Any ideas?

I have also used extjs4 compatibility for migration.

Comment: If you are using chrome, you will get stack trace. So have a look at the stacktrace, find out YOUR file in which this error is coming, and then show us that code. Then we will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have some how fixed those errors. I have changed ext.extend to ext.define. But now i am getting one more error. Network error saying TreeNodeUI.js is not found. Code snippet Ext.define('Ext.tree.ColumnNodeUI', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.TreeNodeUI',
This is in file columnnodeui.js

Answer (score 1):

Are you using all of the resources [outlined here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/), including the [screencasts](http://vimeo.com/23027769)?  The videos take a little time commitment, but I think you'll find them quite helpful as they walk through several examples of how to debug exactly these types of issues.  Learning to debug effectively will be the best way to tackle this type of migration.

Comment: I have followed upto changing ext.reg('','') 2nd argument to string.This have removed most of the errors. But, now i am getting error on Ext.tree.TreeNodeUI. any help ..?:(

Answer (score 0):

There's no class named 'TreeNodeUI' in ExtJS. If you want treepanel, then you need to extend 'treepanel'. Please have a look at examples given on Sencha website before trying out any code.